# Reading txt file into array using scanner

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a text file that looks roughly like this:

> type, distance, length, other,
>
> A, 62, 17, abc,
>
> A, 12, 4,,
>
> A, 6, 90,,
>
> A, 46, 53,,

etc.

Everything is separated by commas, but sometimes there is a blank.  I need to be able to read this data into an array using a scanner (not bufferedreader) and be able to account for the blanks somehow, as well as split by commas.  Later I will need to be able to calculate things with the data in each column.  How do I get this data into the array?

This is what I have so far: (java)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class RunnerAnalysis {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("File: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        inputFile.nextLine();

        String line = inputFile.nextLine();

        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a Scanner, which is IMHO not such a good idea, you can set the delimiter to `,`.

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(...);
inputFile.useDelimiter(",");

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    String type = inputFile.next();
    int distance = inputFile.nextInt();
    int length = inputFile.nextInt();
    String other = inputFile.next();

    // Process...
}
```

---

I prefer using a `BufferedReader` in combination with `String.split(",")`.